# How to protect sheet in google spreadsheet using apps script after data entry

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

So I wanted to protect my data in all of my sheet but after data entry of all editors in google spreadsheet

Comment: In your situation, `all editors` also include yourself?

Comment: Are you trying to protect the whole file, sheet, or only cells/range with new data? Anyway, you will need it to bind it in `onEdit()` function and probably use `protect()`. For the whole file you need to set permissions...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.